# Wordpress Navigation

Tags: menus, navigation

I have my html code for menu as follows:

```
<div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.php" >About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.php" >Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="success.php" >Success Stories</a></li>
        <li><a href="testimonials.php" >Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.php" >Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
```

I have registered sidebar in `functions.php` as follows

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'name'          => __( 'Main Navigation', 'theme_text_domain' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-navigation',
    'description'   => 'Main Navigation Container',
        'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>' );
    register_sidebar( $args );

?>
```

After that i called the dynamic sidebar in `header.php` file as

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-navigation'); ?>
```

But i could not see the menus appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You should hook it  like this :

```
function customwidget_init()
{
$args = array(
    'name'          => __( 'Main Navigation', 'theme_text_domain' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-navigation',
    'description'   => 'Main Navigation Container',
        'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>' );
    register_sidebar( $args );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'customwidget_init');
```

see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) description